# how to have composed primary key in hyperledger composer model file as identifer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, identifier

I have this in my model file in hyperledger composer:

```
participant seller identified by name {
o String name
o String lastName
}
```

but I want to use name and lastName as identifier, anyone knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no composite key feature in Composer - you will have to compose/calculate the key in your code before making calls to Composer.